# Downgrade crystal report version

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Recently I made reports for my ASP.net website using (crystal reports 13.0) it was working well on my local server,but I found that my own web server just supports crystal report (10.5).So how can i convert that reports to 10.5? Is it possible without creating new ones using (10.5).

Comment: While the version of the product has changed, the file format may not have.  Try the report on web server and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading the report to a newer version is not a big deal.
Downgrading is always a problem as there may be the possibility of loss of features added to the newer version.

Comment: But how it can be downgraded ?